# Images folder not loading from Github repo to Github Pages

Tags: github-pages

Website link hosted on Github pages : https://rohanchoudhary.in
Repository Link: https://github.com/therohanchoudhary/Portfolio-Rohan/

When you try inspect element it doesn't load images folder.

Answer (score 0):

please change your image file extension from uppercase to lowercase. Eg:

`<img src="./images/rohan.jpeg" alt="Rohan Choudhary Profile Photo" class="profile-image">`

instead of

`<img src="./images/rohan.JPEG" alt="Rohan Choudhary Profile Photo" class="profile-image">`

Answer (score 0):

I inspected your code, there is a spelling mistake in your Image filename.

The image `https://rohanchoudhary.in/images/cloud.PNG` is not available on the repository instead there is a image `https://rohanchoudhary.in/images/cloud.png` available in the repository.

This gives you a `404` File Not Found error.

So you'll need to fix the following:

```
<img src="./images/cloud.PNG" alt="cloud-img" class="bottom-cloud">
```

To:

```
<img src="./images/cloud.png" alt="cloud-img" class="bottom-cloud">
```

Just rename all the images properly and your error will be solved.